# Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException

Tags: hibernate, connection

I know my case in not single, before I search also, but still think I'm having individual problem.

```
2013-04-13 12:15:04,980 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - <Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [app-context.xml]>
2013-04-13 12:15:05,312 INFO [org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext] - <Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext@8def5d: startup date [Sat Apr 13 12:15:05 EDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy>
2013-04-13 12:15:05,405 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer] - <Loading properties file from class path resource [connection.properties]>
2013-04-13 12:15:05,438 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@c816a9: defining beans [dataSource,transactionManager,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,contactDao,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,sessionFactory]; root of factory hierarchy>
2013-04-13 12:15:05,452 INFO [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] - <Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver>
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2013-04-13 12:15:05,882 INFO [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean] - <Building new Hibernate SessionFactory>
2013-04-13 12:15:06,318 INFO [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager] - <Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@13b499d] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager>
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:596)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy20.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at rus.spring.hibernate.AppOut.main(AppOut.java:18)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root  '@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:925)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4615)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1302)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2483)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2516)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 12 more
```

So, my app-context.xml where I do configure hibernate session anatation etc.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"><value>${jdbc.driverClassName}</value></property>
    <property name="url"><value>${jdbc.connectionValues}</value></property>
    <property name="username"><value>${jdbc.userName}</value></property>
    <property name="password"><value>${jdbc.password}</value></property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref ="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <context:property-placeholder location="connection.properties"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="rus.spring.hibernate" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref ="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="rus.spring.hibernate"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    </props>
    </property>

    </bean>

</beans>
```

My properties file is:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.connectionValues=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernateDB
jdbc.userName=root  
jdbc.password=25051988
```

I just mention this line: 
Access denied for user 'root    '@'localhost' (using password: YES) but my all connection.properties are absolutly right.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Note that error messages says `Access denied for user 'root  '@'localhost'`. You have two extra spaces after `root` in your properties file.